# How can I accomplish the "i dont knw if the naming is right" but accordion modals

Tags: react-native

hello react native developers, I'm trying to create what's attached in the images
[image: not toggled]

while clicking on it should toggle like: [image: toggled]

Comment: Please provide some more information and what is the problem you are facing. No one will create the whole component for you.

Comment: @HarshKukarwadiya The details are pretty much there, there should be a component already built, I just can't seem to get the exact name of it so I can start using it

Comment: @HarshKukarwadiya I think https://octopitus.github.io/rn-sliding-up-panel/ is what I need in a way